# libsass-python compile a file

Tags: python, css, compilation, sass

I recently find a fantastic python library compiling SASS really fast!
[libsass-python](https://github.com/dahlia/libsass-python) seems to be very good and really fast

How I can use it to watch for any change in a sass folder or file and compile it in CSS ?
I do not understand how to pass a file and how to use --watch option

Thanks!

Comment: Watching folder is not possible with libsass-python.

Comment: Use Boussole as @sveetch mentioned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution described here (`--watch` option) was removed from `libsaas-python` since version 0.13.0 [(release notes)](https://github.com/sass/libsass-python/releases/tag/0.13.0), released in 2017.

Therefore this solution will no longer work.
As a replacement, you can use [boussole](https://boussole.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as advertised in a subsequent answer.

The rest of this post can be ignored unless you are using versions older than 0.13.0.

---

According to the help instructions (http://hongminhee.org/libsass-python/sassc.html), you can watch for modifications in file simply with :

```
$ sassc --watch source.scss target.css
```

Now, I get you want to watch all the files contained in a **folder**, and it doesn't seem that the command-line utility provides that.

For what I can tell, I'd see two possible workarounds.

1 : launching several `sassc` instances, one for each of your files. It *pretty dirty*, but doesn't require any effort, and I guess it is okay if you don't have too many files. Don't forget to terminate all the process (with `killall` for instance).

```
$ sassc --watch a.scss a.css & sassc --watch b.scss b.css # etc.
```

This is really not a great way to handle things, but it can be considered a temporary solution if you're in a hurry.

2 : use libsass inside a python program that would trigger compilation when a watched file is saved. To that end you can use another library like [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/index.html) or [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify).

This seems to be a much better way to handle things.

Hope this was helpful, good luck !

Comment: This is what I thought before using it, but there isn't a watch option
Try sassc -h in the command line

Comment: Weird. I did tried the `--watch` option myself. Using 0.5.0 version installed with `pip`. How about you ?

Comment: I did install with `pip install libsass` on OSX

Then, this is the result `sassc: unrecognized option --watch`

I also tried to find any string "watch" in the py code and there is no match at all.

Comment: Sorry. I found the problem and you were right. I installed a C++ version before and I have a symbolic link in /usr/bin; so when I try to call `sassc`, I actually use C++ version. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm also getting an error `no such option: --watch` ... I don't think the Python version has a `--watch` command.. however sveetch's answer using Boussole works great!

Comment: Thank you Jacob for pointing that out. The option was removed from `libsass` years after the answer was posted. I have added a small note on top to reflect that this method is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Boussole](http://boussole.readthedocs.io) that works on top of libsass-python on a per project configuration and comes with a "watch" command (using [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog)).

On top parent of your scss source directory, use:

```
boussole startproject
```

If needed, you can change settings options (from generated `settings.json`) then type:

```
boussole watch
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, the accepted answer does not!