# Flask_Scss not compiling scss file in simple app

Tags: python, flask, sass

I'm trying to use [Flask-Scss](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Scss/) to compile a scss file in my flask app. Here is my app:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_scss import Scss
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
Scss(app, static_dir='static', asset_dir='assets/scss/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This file is in a directory that also contains a `static` directory and `assets` directory. Furthermore, `assets` contains a `scss` directory, which holds the file `test.scss`. When I run the app, I don't see any css files getting created inside of `static`. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Make a request to `/`, what do you see?

Comment: Are you usre assets and static exist in the correct location? Can you provide the layout of your filesystem? From doc: `If no asset directory is found, Flask-Scss will not be activated.` `If no static directory is found, Flask-Scss will not be activated.`

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?= I am at the same point and dont know why flask-scss is not activated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put absolute path for it to work. Assuming your structure is app/**init**.py then this should be your code:

```
Scss(app, static_dir='app/static', asset_dir='app/assets/scss')
```

NOTE: Don't forget to reload the page for the compiling to happen. If you don't reload the page then scss files will not be compiled to css.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [libsass](https://sass.github.io/libsass-python), it works for both Sass and SCSS files. After you `import sass` simply use the compile function with the dirname keyword argument, like this:

```
sass.compile(dirname=('path/to/source', 'path/to/target'))
```

You also have the option to set the output style, for example:

```
sass.compile(dirname=('path/to/source', 'path/to/target'), output_style='compressed')
```

If you want to watch a file or directory for automatic compilation on every edit use [boussole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644595/1544937).